# Maven deploy ignores project version set by maven-versions plugin

Tags: maven, parameters, jenkins, nexus

I have a Maven project "core". In the project's pom.xml, the version is 0.1. 
I use a parameterized build in Jenkins and set a text parameter myNewVersion=3.1.
I also set the following maven goals:

```
versions:set -DnewVersion=${myNewVersion} versions:commit deploy
```

When the being built, maven updates the version in the pom.xml correctly to "3.1". However the maven deploy task deploys my project as "core-0.1", the version being still 0.1. The pom file included in the corresponding 0.1 dir in my Nexus states the version number "3.1".

What can I do to force the maven deploy task to use the correct version set by the maven versions plugin?

Thank you very much for your help.

**EDIT 1:**
To clarify my needs: The version of the project in the POM should not state an actual build version. I use it to determine the compatability of my "core" project to underlying systems and APIs. In more detail: The project "core" gets a "interfaceVersion=3.1" or "interfaceVersion=4.0" parameter from jenkins. This determines which version my core project uses for its dependency to another "libraries" bundle.

Now, I have two Jenkins build jobs, one for 3.1 and one for 4.0 library-project dependency of the core project. Each checks out the same project code from SVN, but passes a different version parameter to the "core" project being build. I want to use this version number as my project's version number in the pom.xml AND as version number of my jar being deployed to the nexus (i.e. core-3.1.jar or core-4.0.jar).

**Edit 2:**
I've come a little further. I just use the version parameter that I set in jenkins as a parameter in my parameterized build section as the project's version number in the pom file. Maven warns about doing this, but it works. However, all my projects depending on "core" now need to specify "${myNewVersion}" as the dependency version, too.

So I try to use the versions-maven-plugin again to set/overwrite the version in the pom file, just as I stated above. However, now I get a "Access denied" error when using maven deploy. If i remove the "versions:set -DnewVersion=${myNewVersion} versions:commit" and just use "deploy", it works. Any clue how to resolve this?

Comment: Why not using the release plugin ?

Comment: AFAIK versions:commit does not really commit to SCM this might done by release:commit ...

Comment: As suggested by @khmarbaise, try out the M2_release plugin. It will automate the POM versioning and take care of your SCM tagging/labelling : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin

Comment: I do not want to tag my SCM (SVN), I want to make sure the mvn:deploy goal deploys using the version number I specify in my jenkins build job. I'm not sure how to achieve this using the maven release plugin. I played around a bit with it, but have no useful results so far.

Comment: I updated my question above with more details. Thank you.

Comment: The message about "Access denied" is produced, cause the Maven way is never deploy a released artifact a second time.

Comment: The access denied was some kind of problem with url resolving in out network.

Comment: @HombreFab Did you come with any solution here? I'm facing the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

In your pom.xml set the version as a variable, like this:

```
<version>${version}</version>
```

Then run maven

```
mvn deploy -Dversion=${myNewVersion}
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue. The "pom.xml" will still have <version>${version}</version> on the artifactory.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone that have the same problem, I had the same issue, and it was related to the `versions` plugin and using an [Aggregator POM](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation). The versions change was not propagated to child projects which does not have its parent set to the aggregator pom.

This can be fixed by [widening](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/set.html#Widening_the_scope_of_the_change) the scope of `versions:set`, ex:

```
versions:set -DgroupId=com.company.* -DartifactId=* -DnewVersion=${myNewVersion} versions:commit deploy
```